# Resize JFrame and Components Based On Computer Resoultion

Tags: java, swing, layout, resize, dimension

I've made a java application in netbeans and am wondering how to have the size of the jframe half the width and height of the computer resolution and also having the components comply with this change. I tried putting code and it did make the frame half the height of the computer resolution but my components, such as buttons and textfields, stopped showing. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Use and appropriate layout manager.  You may also have more sucess of getting answer if you provide a suitable [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 3):

(EDITED)

Set the JFrame's layout manager to [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html). In the properties window of the GridLayout itself (select in the navigator window) set columns to 1 and rows to 2. This should give you what you want and you won't have to get into the code.

This is the key code being called within the `initComponents()` method of your `JFrame` subclass (created by NetBeans) but it is important to understand where it is:

```
    getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(2, 1));
```

I love Netbeans but you do have to understand the basics.

Good luck with your project. Swing is an awesome toolset that was way ahead of it's time.

Comment: But how would I do that on my existing project? What would I change?

Comment: You have to change the layout manager for the JFrame (or whatever is the container that you want to do the halving) to be GridBagaLayout. Then make two grid cells with equal weight. You will then put two containers in those cells and your stuff (buttons, text areas) in those containers.

Comment: You can change the LayoutManger via the NetBeans UI. It should be in the tree of components. It's called the "Navigator." You can also right click on the JFrame and chose "Set Layout."

Comment: These grid cells, do you mean like panels and then putting the respective weights?

Comment: Hey Navio I corrected and tested my solution. Try it again. GridLayout is even simpler and solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As usual in this situation the key is using the right combination of layout managers for your containers. You're probably using NetBeans generated code (something I recommend you avoid until you are *very* comfortable with Swing coding), and it's probably having you use GroupLayout, a fine layout, but one that might not behave as well as you'd like on resizing components. I suggest that you go through the [layout manager tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and try to nest JPanel containers and play with different layouts that re-size well such as GridLayout, GridBagLayout and BorderLayout to try to create the best layout that can re-size well.

Comment: How would I change the layout of my project? I can't edit it in the code because it says that Netbeans takes care of it.

Comment: I agree that you should have a good knowledge of Swing fundamentals, but I don't think you have to be an expert before you can use the awesome Netbeans WYSIWYG environment.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi: Where did I say that one needs to be an expert?

Comment: @Navio53: please read through the layout manager tutorial. Don't edit NetBeans uneditable code section, but rather try to code it by hand. As for what specific layout manager to use, hard to guess without your showing us what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - "Very Comfortable" is close to "expert." You are right it's not the same, but I felt it was too strong. "Comfortable" I think would be more accurate. Either way you are right to point out that it is not WinForms which is less flexible but you can use it knowing zero about the underlying implementation.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi: the guy is stumbling in the dark because he knows absolutely nothing about how to create Swing GUI's other than to drag and drop from NetBeans, and that NetBeans will generate "do not change" code sections. He surely needs to know more than this before he can use NetBeans well, so I think it is time to push him out of his comfort zone.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - You are right to do so, I just didn't want to scare him off of NetBeans by making him think he has to spend 3 weeks understanding how to override the painting of components. Swing is hands down my favorite library, but it is deep and complex. I wish I still used it.